# Using Redis for session store doesn't seem to work

Tags: node.js, session, express, redis

adapting an existing app to Express 4.4.x

Trying to implement redis session store, using the following code:

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
var redis = require('redis').createClient();

app.use(session({
    store: new RedisStore({
        host: '1.1.1.1',
        port: 1234,
        prefix: 'yourprefix:',
        client: redis
    }),
    secret: '.......',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

However, when I run this there is no key stored in redis and I cannot call req.session. I'm sure it's something really simple I've missed or included something in the code which is restricting it. Could also be redis settings?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just got lost in the documentation. Difficult to keep track of express-session, redis, connect-redis and entirely remember the difference between everything.

The simple solution was:

> var redis = require('redis').createClient(**port, host, auth**);

Now it works. I believe I was able to use .createClient(); when the redis server was hosted locally, however now we've moved to a dedicated redis server - these attributes are required.

Thanks, hope this helps somebody else!

Comment: Just to be clear, you will need to define port, host and auth yourself... ie before var redis...

Comment: I don't think you need to create a client separatly. Connect-redis does it for you as it is a dependancy.